# Triple-DES DUKPT CBC PIN variant vs Data variant

Tags: encryption, 3des, cbc-mac, dukpt

Does any know the difference between triple des dukpt decryption algorithm with PIN variant and Data variant?

I have done Triple DESK DUKPT PIN variant, which generate session key from **KSN** and **BDK**. And then decrypt message using the session key.

How about Data variant? How is it different from PIn variant? Thank you

Comment: I see you have multiple questions here with regards to DUKPT. They are however not so much about programming but much more protocol related questions. Those should be really asked at the [IT security](http://security.stackexchange.com) site. One nasty effect of posting at SO is that your questions only have little followed tags. As nobody scans all the questions here your questions will not be noticed much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has been cross-posted and answered on [Security.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27533).